# How can I get the result value in java overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I want to write a program such that if the input is `true`, it adds `a` and `b`, and if the input is `false`, it subtracts `b` from `a`. Also, when it is an `ArrayList`, if the input is `true`, it picks the maximum value, and if the input is `false`, it picks the minimum value.

```
public class Source7_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OverLoading mm = new OverLoading();

        int[] a = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;

        System.out.println("dist(" + mm.a + ", " + mm.b + ", " + true + ") = ");
        System.out.println("dist(" + mm.a + ", " + mm.b + ", " + false + ") = ");
        System.out.println("dist(arr, " + true + ") = ");
        System.out.println("dist(arr, " + false + ") = ");
    }
}

class OverLoading {

    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    int b = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    int dist(int a, int b, boolean d) {
        return d == true ? a + b : a - b;
    }

    int dist(int[] a, boolean d) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            int max, min;
            max = min = a[0];
            if (max < a[j])
                max = a[j];
            if (min > a[j])
                min = a[j];
            return true ? max : min;
        }
    }

}
```

But I can't get the result value.. 
How can I get it?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are not even calling the `dist` function. Inside print statements you are printing a string "dist" instead of calling the method.

Comment: Also in second method maybe you are trying to do `return b ? max : min`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to call these methods but at the moment you are simply appending `Strings`

```
System.out.println("dist(" + mm.a + ", " + mm.b + ", " + true + ") = ");
```

should maybe be

```
System.out.println(mm.dist(mm.a, mm.b, true);
```

**and** as the fields `a` and `b` are part of the class, it would not be necessary to pass them

Comment: Thank you! But how can I get the maximum and mimum value of arraylist? `System.out.println(mm.dist(mm.a[], true);` I wrote the same way as you did but in this case It seems wrong way.. haha

Comment: move `int max, min;` to be fields - after the method has finished you can get their values.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OverLoading
{
    int a = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
int b = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;

int dist(int a, int b, boolean d) {
    return d == true ? a + b : a - b;
}

int dist(int[] a, boolean d) {
        int max, min;
        max = min = a[0];
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if (max < a[j])
            max = a[j];
        if (min > a[j])
            min = a[j];
    }
    return  d == true ? max : min;
}
}

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    OverLoading mm = new OverLoading();

    int[] a = new int[10];
    System.out.println("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("dist(" + mm.a + ", " + mm.b + ", " + true + ") = "+mm.dist(mm.a,mm.b,true));
    System.out.println("dist(" + mm.a + ", " + mm.b + ", " + false + ") = "+mm.dist(mm.a,mm.b,false));
    System.out.println("dist(arr, " + true + ") = "+mm.dist(a,true));
    System.out.println("dist(arr, " + false + ") = "+mm.dist(a,false));
}
}
```

Comment: This is a working code..you can check only by copy pasting this in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php

Comment: No Problem..happy to help :-)